# Confused over variable necessity

Tags: python, variables

What does the `obj=lists[0]` do in the following code?

```
lists = []
infile = open(path, 'rb')
while True:
    try:
        lists.append(pickle.load(infile))
    except EOFError:
        break
obj=lists[0]
while len(lists) > 3:
    lists.pop(0)
print(lists)
infile.close()
```

I have tried to understand it but I cannot seem to see any reason for it.

Comment: For the code you have psoted it does not seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: Probably left over from some refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing.

`obj` is never referred to after its initial assignment, so it has no effect on anything.

The only possible way I could see that line doing anything, is if `lists` was some strange class whose `__getitem__` call has a side effect. For example,

```
class StrangeList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        self[idx] = 23
        return 23

def a():
    x = StrangeList([1,2,3])
    print x

def b():
    x = StrangeList([1,2,3])
    obj = x[0]
    print x

print "Calling a"
a()
print "Calling b"
b()
```

Result

```
Calling a
[1, 2, 3]
Calling b
[23, 2, 3]
```

Here, doing `obj = x[0]` does do something, even though `obj` is never used. But this is a contrived example; for your current code and for 99.9% of the classes you're likely to use in the future, `__getitem__` won't behave this way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is all the code there is, there is no use for it and, as @Daniel Roseman mentioned, it must be a left over from some refactoring.

If there is more code in your program, I would suggest that the variable `obj` is being used to preserve the first value of the list. The loop below it consumes all elements in the list (except the last three), so if you are going to need the original first object in the list, you need to preserve it - hence, the `obj` attribution.